# Activity indicator in a screen

Tags: android, widget, activity-indicator

In my application i want to show an activity indicator.In my application i have an galleryview ,in that if user click on the item in galleryview i will load data from URL and show it in the listview.Between  loading and displaying data i need an indicator.

My activity code:

```
gal.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

            context.getInstance().setAppVariable("sectionurl", adapter.sectionurl[position]);
            ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
            listadapter = new ListViewwithimageAdapter(this);
            list.setAdapter(listadapter);

        }
    });
```

Also i found 1 indicator code:

```
ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(contxt);
      mDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
      mDialog.setCancelable(true);
      mDialog.show();
```

My getview code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

         ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(contxt);
         mDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
         mDialog.setCancelable(false);
         mDialog.show();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
         Bitmap bitmap = DownloadImage(
                 kickerimage[position] );        
//       View listView = convertView;
         if (convertView   == null) 
            {
                //this should only ever run if you do not get a view back            
             LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater) contxt
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
             convertView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.homelistrow, null); 
            }
//       else
//       {
//           holder.removeAllViews();
//       }
//      View listView;
//      if (convertView == null) 
//      {
//          listView = new View(contxt);             
//          LinearLayout holder = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(android.R.id);
////            holder = inflater.inflate(R.layout.homelistrow, null); 
//          System.out.println("pos="+position);
//          System.out.println("item="+getItem(position));
//       else
//       {
            TextView textView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.name_label);
            textView.setText(itemsarray[position]);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.icon);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
//      }
//      else        
//      {
//          listView = (View) convertView;
//      } 
//       }
            mDialog.dismiss();
        return convertView ;        
    }
```

My Logcat:

```
11-28 16:01:55.589: D/AndroidRuntime(788): Shutting down VM
11-28 16:01:55.589: W/dalvikvm(788): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
11-28 16:01:55.589: E/AndroidRuntime(788): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:472)
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:239)
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at com.newspaper.NewsPaperNov28MainGalleryActivity$1.onItemClick(NewsPaperNov28MainGalleryActivity.java:68)
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.widget.Gallery.onSingleTapUp(Gallery.java:864)
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:506)
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.widget.Gallery.onTouchEvent(Gallery.java:839)
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:852)
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
11-28 16:01:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(788):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-28 16:01:55.739: I/dalvikvm(788): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
11-28 16:01:55.739: I/dalvikvm(788): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Actually i placed this code in my getview() in adapter class.But the indicator is not ending its always showing..Please help me ..Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

You need to call

```
mDialog.dismiss();
```

after your loading is done.

EDIT:

I am adding the code which I used for similar task.

```
//This is my AsyncTask which needed some time
new InsertDbTask().execute();


//Actual task
public class InsertDbTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                prepareInsert();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            this.dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            this.dialog.setMessage("Inserting Record In Local DB Please Wait.");
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                this.dialog.dismiss();
            }
            saveButton.setEnabled(true);    // enable save button after execution of prepareInsert().

        }

    }

public void prepareInsert()
{
      // Do something 
}
```

Comment: What was the problem? Dialog is being displayed?

Comment: Please post the code of your getView() method, too. Because I think there is something wrong

Comment: Thanks user1858914..U have preExecute() and PostExecute() in that u performed the action..But in my case where shall i can separate this functionality....

Comment: You can call dialog.dismiss() just before "return convertView" statement

Answer (score 0):

You need to place progress dialog code in `gal.setOnItemClickListener` & when list is loaded dismiss that progress dialog.

Comment: dont add in getview() class. getview called eachtime for creating layout row. so u need to put asynctask code before getting data.

Comment: In gal.setOnItemClickListener click mentod start asyncask with progressdialog on its post execute dismiss dialog & update UI adapter:


put this `ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
            listadapter = new ListViewwithimageAdapter(this);
            list.setAdapter(listadapter);`  in postexecute after u get data

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20244/discussion-between-rohit-lagu-and-subburaj)

Comment: again copy paste: In gal.setOnItemClickListener click mentod start asyncask with progressdialog on its post execute dismiss dialog & update UI adapter: put this ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list); listadapter = new ListViewwithimageAdapter(this); list.setAdapter(listadapter); in postexecute after u get data